# Promotional ads for Genealogy.SE!

Tags: discussion, publicity

Although we're still in beta, ads to promote our site in the genealogical community are important. They should sell what GFH.SE is all about as concisely as possible. Because we haven't yet graduated, we don't have our own personalized flair. It's up to us to design ourselves a set of promotional tools to help spread the word.

This post will serve as the official page to vote on the best ads for our community. Simply enter your design as answer, vote up the ads you like, and comment on how ads can be improved.

---

### Rules (sort of)

1. All ads must be 220 by 250 px. This allows us to use them in community ads on other sites and a host of other places
2. For bonus points, make an A4 and/or Letter (300 dpi) design with the same theme. These are for printing, so please have this readily available in CMYK format. Include these in the answer with your (same-themed) ad.
3. *One* ad per answer please. If you have multiple designs, make multiple answers.

Each ad should include the site url and should note that this site is part of Stack Exchange.

The designs will be numbered (the first being one, second two, and so on) to make it easy to refer to a particular design.

---

### Resources

- You can find the Stack Exchange logo [here](http://stackexchange.com/about/logos), but be sure to follow [these guidelines](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) when using it.
- Ideas for an elevator pitch can be found [here](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

### Design 02

---

[image]

Comment: This one is the best, but they are all good. This sort if thing would give the SE designers some ideas for if we ever do graduate.

Comment: Just a question, do you prefer the tagline (first two lines) of this design, or design 03?

Comment: No strong preference. I like the typographical hierarchy of this one better, but aren't the fonts inconsistent? Maybe the first line should be in the same font family as the other text.

Comment: My mistake. I missed that. I did the mockup with plain Arial, but I somehow forgot to convert that line to the same family here. I'll fix it. Missed that one Design 01 too. Good catch

Comment: I prefer this layout and the tagline of design 3.

Answer (score 1):

### Design 01

---

[image]

Comment: Why is the trailing .SE in small caps when the rest of the title is in title case?

Comment: What is the intent behind the exclamation point after the title?

Comment: Why a "new" site? Or is it a "new Q&A" site?

Comment: Why is genealogy capped when used as a noun but not when adjectival?

Comment: The trailing SE is smaller mainly because it is not a secondary part of the name. Just the hierarchy I chose. The exclamation point is left over from an earlier version that read "join Genealogy... !". I'll fix that. We are relatively new, but I'm still up in the air over whether or not "new" should be in there.

Answer (score 0):

### Design 03

---

[image]

Comment: Same as design 01 except for the tagline'

Answer (score 0):

### Design 04

---

[image]

Comment: Same as design 02 except for minor tweaks and tagline from 03. Same hierarchy as 01 & 02.

Comment: "and genealogy" or "about genealogy"? If "and", to what are the questions and answers related?

Comment: Personally, I think "and" reads better. It's more of a catch phrase than a grammatical sentence. If I used "about", it would read, "Just questions and answers about genealogy", which I think is a bit wordy. Of course, feel free to object.